# Google OAuth 2.0 login without browser

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

There is any way to check the google authentication without using a browser.

I need a standalone application which run and it should get authenticated and then I have get Youtube API to get other information..

This is my sample code..

```
public class Final {

    static final String client_id = "xxx";
    static final String client_secret = "yyy";
    static final String appName = "youtubeSearchSample";

    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    static String access_token = "zzz";

    // static String refreshToken = "yyyyy";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setClientSecrets(client_id, client_secret).build();
            credential.setAccessToken(access_token);
            // credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
            // GoogleCredential
            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                    credential).setApplicationName(appName)
                    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("snippet");
            search.setKey(access_token);
            search.setQ("test");

            // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
            search.setType("video");

            // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
            // application uses.
            // search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults((long) 25);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            System.out.println("searchResponse-->" + searchResponse.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://oauth.io/ has web and mobile SDK's which you can use to get/check google authentication. They still use a browser if a user needs to authenticate, but if a user is authenticated, that can happen behind the scenes. Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but registering your app through that link can get you started.

Comment: Here we are not using a web application itself. we need to authenticate in back end and get the information of you tube api. This is for only one user and not for multiple user.

Comment: What technology are you using for your backend?